# DRF - access request's POST data

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-class-based-views

I do a request to my local server using postman like this:

[image: POSTMan post request]

As you can see it's a post request. In my view (`APIView`) I need access to the json data. But when I try:

```
request.POST
# <QueryDict: {}>
```

or

```
request.data  # ¿?
# AttributeError: 'WSGIRequest' object has no attribute 'data'
```

The only way I can see the sent data is when I access to

```
request.body
# '{\n    "token": "6J3qG4Ji2Jw44eIklKvPYxUgclfGRWHZDKG",\n    "city": "Port Orange",\n    "state": "FL",\n    "formatted_address": "Peach Blossom Blvd 5329",\n    "_zip": "32128"\n}'
```

But this is a `'str'`

```
>>> type(request.body)
<type 'str'>
```

I an trying to access to the request's data in `dispatch()` method. I can do this:

```
req = self.initialize_request(request)
```

This returns a `rest_framework.request.Request` object and I can access to request data. But then I can't call

```
super(FaveoAPIView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
```

Because I get:

```
{
  "status_code": 400,
  "object": "Malformed request.",
  "success": false
}
```

I can'r understand why, I guess that when I call `self.initialize_request()` something change. Any idea?

Comment: What is the actual problem you're trying to solve for here? Overriding the dispatch() method is, in most cases, not actually the best way to go about solving a problem.

Comment: @JoeyWilhelm I don't want to override dispatch, I want to execute some code before the normal View flow. But I need to access to request.data, before my post (or get) method executes.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you should be able to override the `initial()` method on your view in order to achieve what you're attempting. The docstring from the `APIView` class reads:

```
"""
Runs anything that needs to occur prior to calling the method handler.
"""
```

So, it would look something like:

```
class FaveoAPIView(APIView):

    def initial(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FaveoAPIView, self).initial(request, *args, **kwargs)
        # Manipulate request.data to your heart's content here
```

In `APIView`, this is called immediately before your method handler.

Comment: Wihelm I can see this is executed during dispatch and before post or get, but this method is suposed to doesn't return anything, so I can't return a Response with an error message if my validations fails here. Or is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

`super(FaveoAPIView, self).dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)` will call `initialize_request` turning the request into a DRF one. This can only be once therefore it'll fail after that.

Instead of fixing a broken solution, could you rather tell us about your actual issue, i.e. why you need to access the requests data before the view itself is called ?

Comment: There're maybe another way to do this, but I was ising this to check some values in the POST data, to check its data type, or if they are a allowed value, for example, I need an integer, but lt 100 and gt 5. And I'd like apply this methods to all my views. If the request's data does not pass the conditions, I don't wat the POST or GET method to be executed.

Comment: This is what serializers are for.

Comment: I would have to write methods in every serializer, since serializers are executend inside post or get method. I want to avoid execute post or get methods if conditions fails.