# DRF - Define 'mandatory' fields in request

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I was looking at documentation but I am maybe missing something. If I want to receive certain fields in the `request`'s data, how can I define them? I'd like to avoid the `POST` or `GET` method to be executed if the complete fields are not in the `request`'s data.

Example:

I need to receive (application/json):

```
{
  "city": "Port Orange",
  "state": "FL",
  "formatted_address": "Peach Blossom Blvd 5329",
  "_zip": "32128"
}
```

But if I get only

```
{
  "city": "Port Orange",
  "state": "FL",
  "formatted_address": "Peach Blossom Blvd 5329"
}
```

I'd like return a Response with an error message 400 Bad Request. But without executing the `POST` method. How could I do this?

PS. I am using `APIView`

Comment: I am able to access the JSON string in the dispatch method using `request.body`

Comment: Yes, but it's a string, not a dict. But I think I could give it a try.

Comment: Doing a json.loads(json_string) makes it a Python dict.

Comment: As you can see in one of my previous questions (linked before in comments) I realized that, I will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: @Gocht You can add a `_zip` field to your serializer. If the field is not supplied in the request, serializer will become invalid and will automatically return a 400 response.

Comment: @Bansal I am not sure if that will work since request is accessible just once

Comment: @BansalUtkarsh Using request's body as dict worked, thanks for your time dude.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this

```
return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

In your view, return the serializer errors along with the correct status code from `rest_framework.status`

Comment: Thanks dude, but where? _I'd like to avoid the POST or GET method to be executed if the complete fields are not in the request's data_

Comment: In that case you will need to override the `dispatch` method of the APIView which is used to call the appropriate method according to request method.

Comment: I tried that, and it's harder that I thought, please take a look at this previous questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33745533/drf-access-requests-post-data/33751106 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33740697/django-drf-dispatch-method-flow/33743610

Comment: Why do you need to avoid the post method execution?

Comment: I really want to avoid writing validation in every view or serializer, I'd like to write something like `required_fields = {'field_a', 'field_b'}` in every view class (outside the GET or POST). I usually use the dispatch method to do this when working with Django, and I did it, but I have just realized that it is not a good idea with DRF

Comment: You don't need to manually validate the data, its just a simple method call `serializer.is_valid()` Its the standard convention. Overriding the dispatch would only create a mess IMHO.

Comment: Well I think is not possible to di what I usually do with Django, write a class, override dispatch and then extend from my created class.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95370/discussion-between-bansal-utkarsh-and-gocht).